# Material-UI: How to remove the transformation of InputLabel?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Trying to remove some default transformation of `InputLabel` inside a `FormControl`, I wonder if there is a way to remove it instead of having to override each property one by one?

e.g. the following works but have to provide overriding values and leaves other defaults:

```
createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiInputLabel: {
            formControl: {
                position: "unset",
                transform: "none"
```

I am looking for a way to remove the properties entirely:

```
createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiInputLabel: {
            formControl: {} <-- as in nothing in formControl, but this does not work
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `shrink` to `false` in `InputLabelProps` to remove the transformation of the input label when editing.

```js
<TextField InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }} />
```

But the problem is that if you have any value, it will overlap with the label since there is no transformation. The solution is to remove the label if the value is not empty:

```js
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      label={value ? " " : "my label"}
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit little-hooks-1866k]

Comment: Thank you. But that is not what I asked. The way I did it in the question will have the label stay at top left (you can set shrink to true for that), but it will not have the scale down transform (0.75 size), i.e. I want my label at its correct font size. And I am asking if you can remove the transform without overriding it.

Comment: @user1589188 you need to use `transform` to `translate` the label to the top, because of how css transform works, you cannot remove the `scale` (reduce font-size) without removing the `translate` or overriding the `translate` again. So the answer is no.

Comment: @NearHuscarlasrl that is exactly my question. I have shown it works by overriding: `transform: "none"`, I want to know if it is possible to do so by removing the pre-set transform by material-ui? Not in CSS in particular, but more in material-ui to stop it from pre-setting the transform or a way to reassign an empty object `{}` to the style class

Comment: @user1589188 I'm afraid you cannot. The property is called `overrides` for a reason, you can [override](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/95a8386085a0847b0ba1d4facefae43dde7c076e/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createMuiTheme.js#L27-L43) *existing* CSS with your own. But the default style [is created](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/95a8386085a0847b0ba1d4facefae43dde7c076e/packages/material-ui/src/InputLabel/InputLabel.js#L110-L112) at startup so you cannot stop or 'unset' it.